# ¿Por qué no retorna el número correcto de caracteres?

Tags: java, string, regex, archivo

Estoy usando expresiones regulares para contar la cantidad de caracteres de un texto, sin contar espacios.

El problema es que siempre cuenta un caracter de más (es decir, si el texto tiene 476 caracteres, retorna 477, si son 680, retorna 681).

Lo que tengo para contar los caracteres es esto:

```
int characters = text.split("\\S").length;
```

"text" es un string en donde guardé lo que leí desde el .txt.
Utilicé la misma manera para contar oraciones y palabras y no hubo problemas.

Una manera en la que el resultado me dió bien fue haciendo:

```
int characters = text.replaceAll(" ", "").split("").length;
```

Pero siento que no tendría que ser necesario el replaceAll()

También podría simplemente restarle 1, pero quiero saber por qué pasa esto.

Por ejemplo, este fragmento de texto: Retorna que tiene 477 caracteres, pero al probar en *regex101*, hay 476 matches.

> This is the page of the Simple English Wikipedia. A place where people work together to write encyclopedias in different languages. That includes children and adults who are learning English. There are 142,262 articles on the Simple English Wikipedia. All of the pages are free to use. They have all been published under both the Creative Commons License 3 and the GNU Free Documentation License. You can help here! You may change these pages and make new pages. Read the help pages and other good pages to learn how to write pages here. You may ask questions at Simple talk.

Comment: Lo único que se viene a la cabeza es que si dices que la cadena viene de un txt, pueda que este tomando en algún punto el carácter '\n'

Comment: Tu código me retorna 476 caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

No sé muy bien cuál la fuente del error, porque de hecho a mí con el texto de ejemplo que has puesto me devuelve `472`. De todas formas creo que no es una buena opción usar `split` con una expresión regular `\S` para contar caracteres ya que el resultado son todo vacíos y espacios. Además de esta forma quita los resultados vacíos que haya al final del resultado.

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
> the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
> strings are therefore not included in the resulting array

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Podrías hacerlo de muchas formas alternativas, como por ejemplo:

```
long count = text.chars().filter(c -> c != ' ').count();
```

Comment: Tal vez mi problema esté en como estoy leyendo el archivo (más allá de la forma de contar los caracteres). Probé y si lo cambio también me da 472.

Answer (score 2):

En resumen, no uses `split()` porque te va a dar un resultado incierto. En cambio buscá **la cantidad de coincidencias** con [`Matcher.results().count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) (Java 9).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
final String regex = "\\S";
final String string = "This is the page of the Simple English Wikipedia. A place where people work together to write encyclopedias in different languages. That includes children and adults who are learning English. There are 142,262 articles on the Simple English Wikipedia. All of the pages are free to use. They have all been published under both the Creative Commons License 3 and the GNU Free Documentation License. You can help here! You may change these pages and make new pages. Read the help pages and other good pages to learn how to write pages here. You may ask questions at Simple talk.";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

long caracteres = matcher.results().count();

System.out.println("Caracteres: "  + caracteres);
// Caracteres: 476
```

No hay motivo para complicarla, si se buscan coincidencias, hay que contar las coincidencias, no los elementos que no coinciden (creo que usás un triple negativo en este caso!! jaja). -Ya sé, son más líneas de código para algo tan sencillo, pero (1) es más eficiente y (2) estás programando en Java así que no vale quejarse por la cantidad de líneas!

---

---

**Sobre todo lo que venías comentando, te respondo que "no"...**

1. > sin contar espacios.

   Sin contar **espacios en blanco**, no solamente espacios. `\s` coincide con `[ \t\n\r\f]` (espacio, tab, salto de línea, retorno, salto de página).
2. > El problema es que siempre cuenta un caracter de más

   Porque no estás contando *cantidad de caracteres* sino la cantidad de elementos del array devuelto por [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Pero se **eliminan** los elementos **vacíos** del final del array.

   Lo repito: se **eliminan** los elementos **vacíos** del final del array... Eso significa que al hacer un split por todos los caracteres que no son espacios en blanco vas a obtener resultados como:

   ```
   int todoVacio       = "prueba".split("\\S").length;         // --> 0
   int unCaracterAntes = "2 prueba".split("\\S").length;       // --> 2
   int unCaracterAntes = "prueba 3".split("\\S").length;       // --> 7
   int espacioFinal    = "prueba ".split("\\S").length;        // --> 7
   int enterFinal      = "prueba\r\n".split("\\S").length;     // --> 7
   int palabras        = "abcd efgh".split("\\S").length;      // --> 5
   ```

   Por eso está mal usar `split()`, porque te va a devolver los elementos vacíos alrededor de cada caracter que no es un espacio en blanco, pero eliminando los elementos vacíos del final. ¿Viste cómo un espacio en blanco al final cambia el resultado?

   Hmmmm... Si no lo estás viendo, te recomiendo contar con los dedos, cuántos elementos hay "*alrededor de cada caracter que no es un espacio en blanco, desde el inicio del string hasta el último espacio en blanco*"

   [image: flechas marcando "abcd * efgh"]
3. > retorna 477

   Puede que tengas un salto de línea al final del string.
4. > Una manera en la que el resultado me dió bien fue haciendo:
   >
   > ```
   > int characters = text.replaceAll(" ", "").split("").length;
   > ```

   Bueno, esto no tiene *nada* que ver. Para empezar, estás remplazando solamente espacios, no espacios en blanco. Y, por otro lado, estás generando un array que contiene cada uno de los caracteres, por lo que tampoco tenés el problema de elementos vacíos al final.
5. > Pero siento que no tendría que ser necesario el replaceAll()

   Exacto, no es necesario porque es redundante, al igual que es redundante usar split() en cada coincidencia, cuando lo único que importa es la cantidad de coincidencias.

   Y de alguna forma, también es excesivo usar regex para contar caracteres de un texto, pero ahí ya estamos en un límite delgado que queda a elección del consumidor.
6. > También podría simplemente restarle 1

   No. Demostrado en punto 2.
7. > pero al probar en regex101, hay 476 matches

   Porque son "matches" (coincidencias), no elementos alrededor de las coincidencias. Además, regex101 usa un motor de expresiones regulares que difiere mucho del utilizado por Java. Para muchas de las pruebas que hagas, te va a dar igual, pero recordá que no es lo mismo y que va a darte resultados diferentes en algunos casos.

Comment: Wow gracias, empecé hace poco a programar en Java (y en general) y esto me viene re bien